# Find the farthest pairs of two points in 2-dim

Tags: regions, distance, subset

I wonder if Mathematica can find the pairs of two points that are the farthest in a given list.

Let's say a list, `XYlist`, of points with (x,y) coordinates.

```
XYlist = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {y, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 100}], 1]
```

We, humans, can easily find out that the following two pairs have the farthest distance in the `XYlist` by, for example, plotting the points:

```
{{0,0},{100,100}}
{{100,0},{0,100}}

ListPlot[XYlist, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I, however, have not had any good idea of how to instruct Mathematica to find out the pairs from the list.

A close way I've got is using `BoundingRegion`.

```
br = BoundingRegion[XYlist, "MinDisk"]
(* Disk[{50, 50}, 50 Sqrt[2]] *)
max = 2*br[[2]]
(* 100 Sqrt[2] *)
```

It gives the minimum area `Disk` that includes all the points. In the above example, this method can correctly find out the farthest distance between the points of the list. However, it does not tell which pairs give the farthest distance, and furthermore, it does not work if the two points of the farthest pairs are not on a diameter of the returned `Disk`.

Another way is using `Subsets` and creating all the possible pairs at first, then checking the distance one by one:

```
ss = Subsets[XYlist, {2}]
nl = Parallelize[Norm /@ Subtract @@@ ss]
max = Max[nl]
pos = Position[nl, max]
pairs = Extract[ss, pos]
(* {{{0, 0}, {100, 100}}, {{100, 0}, {0, 100}}} *)
```

However, this method is very memory-consuming and slow, therefore it is not realistic if the number of points gets large.

Because `BoundingRegion` can find the minimum area `Disk` in a flush, which I think calculates fundamentally similar things, I can't help expecting there exist some very fast methods.

In the case that there are multiple pairs with the farthest distance, I want to get all the pairs.

Do you guys have any good ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The brute force method scales as $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, where $n$ is the number of points. As I understand, even a faster algorithm is desired. In principle, it is possible to speed up by divide and conquer method. Find out the smallest rectangle containing all points and divide it into $10\times10$ cells. Find a pair of furthest non-empty cells, this operation is constant in the number of points $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Divide the 2 cells further and repeat the procedure until only 1 point in each cell remains. The overall scaling should be $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$

Comment: The algorithm can be more complicated if there are many pairs of furthest points, e.g regular $n$-gon. What do you expect in this case?

Comment: @yarchik Yes. The actual my case could contain multiple pairs with the exact same distance that is the farthest.

Comment: @yarchik, I believe this algorithm fails. Consider the 3x3 cell case for ease of demonstration. if you have a point in the bottom left cell, and then a point at the far edge of the top-center cell, and a point at the closest corner of the top-right cell, the algorithm will decide to focus on bottom-left + top-right, but in reality the top-center point is most distant from the bottom-left point.

Comment: For more discussion of algorithms, here's a SO post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736290/how-to-find-two-most-distant-points. Convex hull seems to be the standard.

Comment: @Kaia I didn't completely work out my idea, therefore, I presented no solution. However, we do not need to assume that cells are non-intersecting. They should just cover the rectangle in such a way that if the distance between the cell centres A and B is larger than between the centres C and D, $d(A,B)>d(C,D)$ then the same holds for any points ($a, b, c, d$) from the respective cells  $d(a,b)>d(c,d)$.

Comment: @yarchik yeah, that's fair. I'm struggling to come up w/ an arrangement of cells like that, but it seems likely one exists. Interesting! I doubt the scaling is actually O(log(n)) because you also have to determine what cells are empty, which will ultimately involve iterating the list of points. But it still seems like a potentially novel method

Comment: @TaikiBessho Your attempt with BoundingRegion works well and quite fast if you add `mincircle = RegionBoundary[BoundingRegion[XYlist, "MinDisk"]]; zwp = Select[pts, RegionMember[mincircle, #] &]; fp = MaximalBy[Subsets[zwp, {2}], Apply[ EuclideanDistance]](*{{0, 0}, {0, 100}, {100, 0}, {100, 100}}*)`

Comment: I'm surprised that there is no `MaxDistance` function in the **FunctionRepository** (https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository)...

Comment: Interestingly enough one can measure the maximum distance in v13.3 quite efficiently (seems to scale roughly linearly), but not acquire information on actual points involved: `RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {1000000, 2}] // Point // 
 RegionFarthestDistance[#, #] &`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say you have random points:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10000, 2}];
```

It would be useful to find the `ConvexHullRegion` and find distances between the points at the boundaries. This can be calculated in the following ways, as both outputs are identical. We will use `bpts`.

```
reg = ConvexHullRegion[pts]
bpts = PolygonCoordinates[reg] // Sort
cpts = Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[reg, 0] // Sort

farthest = 
 Union @@ MaximalBy[Tuples[bpts, 2], Apply@EuclideanDistance]
```

> {{-99.1393, 98.7636}, {99.9366, -98.131}}

Visualization:

```
Region[reg
 , Epilog -> {Black, Point[pts]
   , AbsolutePointSize[8], Red
   , Point@farthest
   }
 ]
```

[image]

I hope you can find some usable pointers from this answer.

Comment: Updated to include the definition for `reg`. Sorry about the earlier omission.

Comment: Is  this a property of `ConvexHull`that it contains the points with maximal distance?

Comment: [Similar post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056061/maximum-distance-between-points-in-a-convex-hull) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667070/max-distance-between-2-points-in-a-data-set-and-identifying-the-points). I can't say that I know the rigorous answer @UlrichNeumann.

Comment: Note that the `Union` may have unintended behavior. If there are multiple pairs with the farthest distance and they share a point, the information is lost that which two points are paired.

Comment: I think using `Subsets` instead of `Tuples` may help. `Subsets` doesn't create duplicate pairs with the same points but in the opposite ordering. Therefore, deleting duplicated entries using `Union` will not be needed.

Answer (score 12):

***upd: fixed the error of farthestPointsDistance case. The final code  is so verbose, whereas the result is definitely true.***

---

You can implement your own functions `closestPointsDistance` and `farthestPointsDistance`.

## farthestPointsDistance✅

[Rotating Calipers Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers#Shamos%27s_algorithm), $\text{average }\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];

dist[p1_, p2_] := Norm[p2 - p1];


(*really naive, so slow sortPointsCounterClockwise*)
sortPointsCounterClockwise[pts_] := 
  Module[{center = Mean[pts], angles}, 
   angles = ArcTan @@ (# - center) & /@ pts;
   pts[[Ordering[angles]]]];

convexHull[pts_] := 
  sortPointsCounterClockwise@MeshCoordinates@ConvexHullMesh@pts;

TriangleArea[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
  Abs[(p1[[1]]*(p2[[2]] - p3[[2]]) + p2[[1]]*(p3[[2]] - p1[[2]]) + 
      p3[[1]]*(p1[[2]] - p2[[2]]))/2];



(*Proposed by Preparata and Shamos in 1985 that avoided calculation of angles *)
GetAllAntiPodalPairs[p_List] := 
 Module[{n = Length[p], i0, i = 1, j, j0}, i0 = n;
  j = i + 1;
  While[TriangleArea[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], 
     p[[Mod[j + 1, n, 1]]]] > 
    TriangleArea[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], p[[Mod[j, n, 1]]]], 
   j = Mod[j + 1, n, 1]];
  j0 = j;
  Reap[While[i != j0, i = Mod[i + 1, n, 1];
     Sow[{i, j}];
     While[
      TriangleArea[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], 
        p[[Mod[j + 1, n, 1]]]] > 
       TriangleArea[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], p[[Mod[j, n, 1]]]],
       j = Mod[j + 1, n, 1];
      If[{i, j} != {j0, i0}, Sow[{i, j}]];];
     If[TriangleArea[p[[j]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], 
        p[[Mod[j + 1, n, 1]]]] == 
       TriangleArea[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], p[[Mod[j, n, 1]]]],
       If[{i, j} != {j0, i0}, Sow[{i, Mod[j + 1, n, 1]}], 
        Sow[{Mod[i + 1, n, 1], j}]];];]][[2, 1]]]





pts = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {50, 2}];
polygonPoints = sortPointsCounterClockwise@convexHull@pts;
antiPodalPairs = GetAllAntiPodalPairs@polygonPoints;
numberOfPolygonPoints = Length[polygonPoints];
calculateDistance =(((dist @@ {polygonPoints[[Mod[#1, numberOfPolygonPoints, 1]]], polygonPoints[[Mod[#2, numberOfPolygonPoints, 1]]]}) &) @@ # &);
calculateDistance /@ antiPodalPairs // Max

(* bruteForce to verify the result. *)
dist @@ # & /@ Subsets[pts, {2}] // Max



GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[Graphics[{(*Draw the polygon*){EdgeForm[Directive[Black]], 
      FaceForm[None], Polygon[polygonPoints]},(*Draw the anti-
     podal pairs*){Red, PointSize[Large], 
      Point[{polygonPoints[[antiPodalPairs[[i, 1]]]], 
        polygonPoints[[antiPodalPairs[[i, 
            2]]]]}]},(*Draw lines connecting anti-
     podal pairs*){Blue, Dashed, 
      Line[{polygonPoints[[antiPodalPairs[[i, 1]]]], 
        polygonPoints[[antiPodalPairs[[i, 2]]]]}]}}], {i, 
    Length[antiPodalPairs]}], UpTo[2] (*Maximum 2 plots in a row*)], 
 Frame -> All]
```

```
maxPointsPairs = 
  MaximalBy[antiPodalPairs, calculateDistance ];

maxPoints = 
  Part[{polygonPoints[[#1]], polygonPoints[[#2]]} & @@@ 
    maxPointsPairs, 1];

(*Visualization*)ListPlot[pts, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[maxPoints], Green, 
   Line[maxPoints]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

[image]

## closestPointsDistance✅

[Divide-and-conquer Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/), $\text{average }\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$

```mathematica
euclideanDistance[p1_, p2_] := EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]

bruteForce[points_] := 
 Module[{minDistance = Infinity, dist, minPoints}, 
  Do[dist = euclideanDistance[points[[i]], points[[j]]];
   If[dist < minDistance, minDistance = dist; 
    minPoints = {points[[i]], points[[j]]}], {i, 
    Length[points] - 1}, {j, i + 1, Length[points]}];
  {minDistance, minPoints}]

stripClosest[strip_, d_, pair_] := 
 Module[{minDistance = d, dist, minPoints = pair}, 
  Do[dist = euclideanDistance[strip[[i]], strip[[j]]];
   If[dist < minDistance, minDistance = dist; 
    minPoints = {strip[[i]], strip[[j]]}], {i, Length[strip] - 1}, {j,
     i + 1, Min[i + 7, Length[strip]]}];
  {minDistance, minPoints}]

closestPointsDistance[points_] := 
 Module[{mid, midPoint, dl, dr, d, pair, strip, result}, 
  If[Length[points] <= 3, Return[bruteForce[points]]];
  mid = Ceiling[Length[points]/2];
  midPoint = points[[mid]];
  dl = closestPointsDistance[Take[points, mid]];
  dr = closestPointsDistance[Drop[points, mid]];
  {d, pair} = If[First[dl] < First[dr], dl, dr];
  strip = Select[points, Abs[#[[1]] - midPoint[[1]]] < d &];
  result = stripClosest[strip, d, pair];
  result]

minDistPoints[points_List] := 
 Module[{sortedPoints}, sortedPoints = SortBy[points, First];
  closestPointsDistance[sortedPoints]]
```

```mathematica
pts = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {50, 2}];
{minDist, minPoints} = minDistPoints[pts];
Print[minDist];

(*Visualization*)
ListPlot[pts, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[minPoints], Green, 
   Line[minPoints]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

```
(* bruteForce to verify the result. *)
euclideanDistance @@ # & /@ Subsets[pts, {2}] // Min
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to beat the $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ scaling in the worst case scenario?

Answer (score 7):

```
XYlist = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {y, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 100}], 1];
region = ConvexHullMesh[XYlist] ;
coordinates = MeshCoordinates[region] ;
matrix = DistanceMatrix[coordinates] ;
max = Max[matrix] ;

{i, j}= Transpose[Position[matrix, max] ] ;
Transpose[{coordinates[[i]], coordinates[[j]]}] // Column
(* or *)
Partition[coordinates[[Flatten[Position[matrix, max]]]], Last[Dimensions[coordinates]]]
```

Comment: I don't get what your `Transpose` is for. I thought the last two lines of your answer can be replaced with the following: Part[coordinates, #] & /@ Position[matrix, max] // Column. Is this correct?

Comment: @TaikiBessho, take a look at `DistanceMatrix` docs. `Max` returns indices of matrix, transpose is used to relate them to list of points, sure, a better approach can be used with part or extract

Answer (score 6):

`Nearest`gives a more direct way I think. Therefor we only use the last point found by pointwise `Nearest`-search

```
pts = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {100 , 2}];
maxpair =Map[(np = Nearest[pts, #, All][[-1]]; {#, np,Sqrt[(np - #) . (np - #)]}) &, pts];
```

maxpair contains a list of point-pairs with maximal distance.

```
max=Select[maxpair, #[[3]] == Max[maxpair[[All, 3]]] &]
Graphics[{Point[pts], Red, Line[max[[All, {1, 2}]]]}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nearest tends to be O(n log n) or so, and here it is applied n times, so that's worse than O(n^2) in toto.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That is of course correct, but QP only asked for a simple solution

Answer (score 5):

This is a variation of @Syed's answer. Distance computation of convex hull boundary points is improved by using `DistanceMatrix` - which is very well optimised, even if half of the matrix is unnecessary. This optimisation is beneficial when there's lots of boundary points (try generating input with `N@CirclePoints[1000]` for instance). Both methods suffer from the fact that memory usage grows by the square of the number of the boundary points...

```
With[{bpts = PolygonCoordinates@ConvexHullMesh@pts}, 
 DistanceMatrix[bpts, DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance] //
   bpts[[FirstPosition[#, Max@Flatten@#, {2}]]] &]
```

To avoid this memory usage issue, one can attempt to implement a function which doesn't use memory unnecessarily for storage of matrices or tuple lists:

```
farthestPair[pts_] :=
 ParallelTable[
   pts[[i + 1 ;;]] - ConstantArray[pts[[i]], Length@pts - i] //
     Map@Norm //
    With[{pos = First@PositionLargest@#},
      {#[[pos]], pos + i}] &,
   {i, Length@pts - 1}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"] //
  With[{pos = First@PositionLargest[#[[All, 1]]]},
    pts[[{pos, #[[pos, 2]]}]]] &

farthestPair@PolygonCoordinates@ConvexHullMesh@pts
```

It must be stated neither `DistanceMatrix` nor the above can't compete performance-wise with the Rotating Calipers algorithm since its complexity is $\text{average }\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$, and this is obviously $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, but at least this implementation is easy to understand and could also trivially be generalised to three dimensions. Also it should be noted that the $n$ is the number of boundary points of the convex hull, which is typically small in comparison to all input points.

---

@138_Aspen's Rotating Calipers is *much* faster with large number of boundary points though, so I decided to write it to use a compiled function:

```
farthestPoints =
  With[{rotatingCalipers =
     FunctionCompile[
      Function[Typed[p, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 2]],
       Module[
        {area =
          Abs[#1[[1]] (#2[[2]] - #3[[2]]) +
              #2[[1]] (#3[[2]] - #1[[2]]) +
              #3[[1]] (#1[[2]] - #2[[2]])] &,
         res = {}},
        Module[{n = Length[p], i0, i = 1, j, j0}, i0 = n;
         j = i + 1;
         While[area[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], 
            p[[Mod[j + 1, n, 1]]]] > 
           area[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], p[[Mod[j, n, 1]]]], 
          j = Mod[j + 1, n, 1]];
         j0 = j;
         While[i != j0, i = Mod[i + 1, n, 1];
          AppendTo[res, {i, j}];
          While[area[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], 
             p[[Mod[j + 1, n, 1]]]] > 
            area[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], p[[Mod[j, n, 1]]]], 
           j = Mod[j + 1, n, 1];
           If[{i, j} != {j0, i0}, AppendTo[res, {i, j}]];];
          If[area[p[[j]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], 
             p[[Mod[j + 1, n, 1]]]] == 
            area[p[[i]], p[[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]], p[[Mod[j, n, 1]]]], 
           If[{i, j} != {j0, i0}, 
             AppendTo[res, {i, Mod[j + 1, n, 1]}], 
             AppendTo[res, {Mod[i + 1, n, 1], j}]];];];
         res]]]]},
   
   With[{p = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[#], 2][[1, 1]]},
     p[[#]] & /@ rotatingCalipers[p] // 
       TakeLargestBy[Apply@SquaredEuclideanDistance, 1] //
      First] &];
```

It finds farthest points in a 10000 point boundary set on a circle in half a second (`DistanceMatrix` takes 9 seconds on my laptop):

```
(Timing@*farthestPoints)@RandomSample@N@CirclePoints[10000]

(* {0.480575, {{-0.895386, -0.445292}, {0.895386, 0.445292}}} *)
```